# Generating a Date Span from a Table with Monthly Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say we have a table that looks like this in SQL Server 2012:

```
YYYYMM | Mbr_ID | Product_ID
----------------------------
201501 | 000001 | AA
201502 | 000001 | AA
201503 | 000001 | AB
201504 | 000001 | AA
201505 | 000001 | AA
201506 | 000001 | AA
```

There will be multiple members, and they might switch products multiple times, but never within a given month.

I am looking to turn this into a span table, something like the following:

```
CMonth_Start | CMonth_End | Mbr_ID | Product_ID
-----------------------------------------------
201501       | 201502     | 000001 | AA
201503       | 201503     | 000001 | AB
201504       | 201506     | 000001 | AA
```

If I try to do this using MIN(YYYYMM) and MAX(YYYYMM), I would only get the outer span (201501-201506) for the first product. I know there's got to be some way to do this, and I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't think of it right now. I would really appreciate any help you all could give me, thanks for reading!

Comment: i'm not 2 familiar with span tables, but this link may help - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/can-a-partitioned-table-span-on-multiple-files-across-different-file-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(YYYYMM) AS CMonth_Start, MAX(YYYYMM) AS CMonth_End, 
       Mbr_ID, Product_ID
FROM (
SELECT Mbr_ID, Mbr_ID, Product_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Mbr_ID ORDER BY YYYYMM) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Mbr_ID, Product_ID ORDER BY YYYYMM) AS grp
FROM mytable ) AS t
GROUP BY Mbr_ID, Product_ID, grp
```

`grp` identifies slices of consecutive records having the same `Product_ID` value per `Mbr_ID`. Using this field in an outer query we can get `MIN` / `MAX` values of `YYYYMM` per `Product_ID` value per `Mbr_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

To identify groups of identical values in sequence, you can use a difference of row numbers:

```
select mbr_id, product_id, min(yyyymm) as month_start, max(yyyymm) as month_end
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by mbr_id order by yyyymm) -
              row_number() over (partition by mbr_id, product_id order by yyyymm)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by mbr_id, grp, product_id;
```

To understand how this works, just run the subquery to see what `grp` value looks like.